# How to show images from another table

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables and need to show the first 2 images from `images` table that is linked with the id from `news` table for each id of the news table.

```
<?php

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `id`, `title`, `main_image`, `services` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $main_image, $services);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $news[] = ['id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'main_image' => $main_image, 'services' => $services];
}

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT n.id, i.file_name FROM news AS n INNER JOIN images AS i ON n.id = i.new_id LIMIT 2');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $file_name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $images[] = ['id' => $id, 'file_name' => $file_name];
    
}

foreach ($news as $new) {
    $service = explode(", ", $new['services']);
    if (in_array('Photo', $service)) {
?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card">
              <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                   <div class="row g-0">
                        <div class="col-6">
                             <div class="h-100 me-1 " style="background-image: url(../uploads/<?= $new['main_image'] ?>); background-size: cover;">

                              </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                          <div class="vstack gap-1 h-100">
                                <div class="h-50 " style="background-image: url(../uploads/<?= $images['file_name'] ?>); background-size: cover;"></div>
                                     <div class="h-50  bg-dark-overlay-3 overflow-hidden" style="background-image: url(../uploads/<?= $images['file_name'] ?>); background-size: cover;">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                                                        <a class="btn-link text-white mb-0 stretched-link" href="#"> Vidi sve </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body px-0 pt-3">
                                    
                                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="post-single-3.html" class="btn-link text-reset fw-bold"><?= $new['title'] ?></a></h5>
                                    
                                    <ul class="nav nav-divider align-items-center d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <div class="nav-link">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$images['file_name']` will not work, you need `$images[0]['file_name']` and `$images[1]['file_name']`

Comment: This shows me an image from id = 1 for each new. Need to show me for id = 2 images where is in images table new_id  = 2. But thank you

Comment: `$images` should become multi-dimensional, `$images[$id][] = $file_name;`, then access via `$images[$new['id']][0]`, etc.

Comment: If you mean to do this `<div class="h-50 " style="background-image: url(../uploads/<?= $images[$new['id']][0] ?>); background-size: cover;"></div>` this not working. If you can check my code and show me where is my problem.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what's happening, an error? No output? Please do `var_dump($images)` and check the array is being populated OK.

Comment: Don't have output, don't show images. With `var_dump($images)`

`array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(106) ["file_name"]=> string(16) "_HIM9854 (1).jpg" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(106) ["file_name"]=> string(12) "_HIM9874.jpg" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(109) ["file_name"]=> string(12) "_HIM9854.jpg" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(109) ["file_name"]=> string(12) "_HIM9874.jpg" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(109) ["file_name"]=> string(12) "_HIM9920.jpg" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(109) ["file_name"]=> string(14) "UHD_0975_1.jpg" } } }`

Comment: OK the reason it is not working is because you did not change the code that creates the `$images` array.

Comment: I don't understand what to do now.

Comment: `$images[$id][] = $file_name;` in the while loop after you get your images from db.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you. Please write here as answer, I will approve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are building `$images` as an indexed array instead of an associative array. Then when you iterate through the news articles, accessing it via `$image['file_name']` does not work because the key `file_name` does not exist in the array.

To make it work, you need to change how you create the `$images` array. The id of the news article needs to be the key that you append filenames inside.

`$images[$id][] = $file_name`

Then when you are going through the news articles, you access it by getting the id from the news article:

`<?= $images[$new['id']][0] ?>`